# LG Bello II - Block numbers

Tags: lg, call-screening

How do I block numbers on LG Bello II?
I get a lot of calls from mr. "Unknown" so I would mostly like to block those. **If possible** I would prefer not to install extra apps for this.

I tried following a couple of guides I found but my phone doesn't seem to have what's needed. My settings have no tabs and I don't see anything called "Call rejection" or just "Calls".
I recently bought this and have not done major things with it, as in no rooting. I've only installed a task killer and a VPN app.
I'm from the pc world and no mobile expert.

- Model number: LG-X150
- Software version: V10g-EUR-XXX
- Android version: 5.0
- Kernel version: 3.10.54+
- Build number: LRX21M

Comment: AFAIK this is not a standard Android feature.  If you can't locate it using Izzy's answer below, you may well have to use an app. That could be an automation app or standalone. Let me know if you favour automation approach

Comment: @beeshyams I don't know the difference of the two.

Comment: See app used[here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160906/131553) trigger would be incoming calls unknown number and action reject calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your phone app, switch to the call log tab. Look for the entry you want to block and tap that. You should see a button/link labeled "more" or "details", tap that. On the next page (which shows details on the call), tap the "overflow menu" on the top-right of the screen (the "3 stapled dots"). Select "Add to block list". Done.

**Note:** I've verified that on my device running Lollipop (Android 5.1). Still, this feature might not be available on all devices. According to [an article on DigitalTrends](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-block-phone-calls-on-your-android-smartphone/):

> There is no universal path for blocking contacts on Android smartphones, and it’s a feature the vanilla versions of Android Lollipop and Marshmallow oddly omit. But some devices allow users to enable a per-number blocking mode through the phone’s settings.

So if that feature does not exist on your device, first cross-check with the linked article for possible other locations. If it really cannot be found, you'll have no choice but to revert to a third-party-app for this feature.

Btw, for LG (as you mention your device is an LG device) the linked article writes:

> LG’s made it relatively simple to build an auto-reject list on its handsets. To start, open the Phone app. Tap the 3-dot menu in the top right corner, and from the dropdown menu that appears select *Call Settings > Call reject > Reject calls from.* Select the Plus icon, and then add the number you’d like to block from the call log or your contacts. You can also find it by going to *Settings > Wireless and networks > Call > Call reject > Reject calls from.*

Comment: Unfortunately none of it is possible, so I'm going to look for a third party app.

Comment: Sad to read that. But in this case, for a starter, may I recommend you my app listing on [Call Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97)s? If you can't identify one matching your needs, be welcome to our SoftwareRecs sister site.