# How to set one Ringtone for Contacts and another for non contacts?

Tags: contacts, ringtone

Is there an Android App that can perform one ring for anyone in my Contacts and another ring for anyone **not** in my Contacts?

I know how to go in and set individual ringtones, but I have 350 contacts.

Actually, all I would need is an App that sets a ringtone for any number that is not in my Contacts list.

If not, would that be difficult to create?

Comment: The [Group Ringtone app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.insadco.groupringtone&gl=US) will automatically set a ringtone for all your contacts. Then your system ringtone will only ring for unknown numbers.  It costs $2 for ad-free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Automation is the preferred option. Many apps are available. I prefer using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) , since it is free (upto 5 macros) and easy to learn. To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)

---

Your macro would look like this

- **Macro : Ringtone for non contacts** (name of macro )

**Trigger**: *Call Incoming* →*Select Contact* → *Non Contact*

**Action**: *Ringtone Configure* → Select from drop down

**Constraints**: None ( Macro runs always )

Related [Custom ring tone for callers who block their caller ID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/142733/131553)

Comment: The write-up on the linked topic is much better. I couldn't quite get it to work using the info here. No one has called yet, but for now I think it is solved. I see a little GEAR icon in the top. When I pull the menu down, I see MacroDroid. Do I need to keep it there at the top, or can that notification be dismissed?

Comment: Thanks. 1. I have linked the similar write up at end of first paragraph and added at end relevant write up. 2. It should work, it's a simple macro. Once you test, please remember to mark it as accepted 3. That gear icon is **very much*" required for the app to function correctly as you can see in settings

Answer (score 6):

You can do this on android by going to contacts, then groups tab.

You then need to click the menu button and create a new group. Give it a name and choose a ring tone then click add members and click select all (top left). This will add all your stored 'known' contacts to the group, and will use the selected ringtone for their incoming calls.

Anyone who rings who is not in this group will use the normal default ringtone.

Hope this helps
Dan

Comment: This only works if you remember to add every single contact to a group every time. Not practical.

Comment: And sadly, we no longer have Groups.  Instead we have Labels, and I haven't found a way to set a ringtone for a Label.  (You can do it for email notifications!)

Answer (score 1):

In Android 7, you can go to contacts, then click the 3 dots to enter the groups tab, there should be a group called "my contacts", then change the default ringtone for that group.

Comment: I'm not seeing groups anymore in Android 8...