# How can I set a ringtone for a group of contacts with a certain label?

Tags: contacts, ringtone, google-contacts, contact-groups

I want to set the ringtone for each contact with a particular label on my Pixel 2 (Android 11). Labels are a thing that contacts can have in the [default android contacts app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts) (from Google). There seems to be a lot of answers out there about doing this, but only when the contacts app has something *specifically* named "groups". There is nothing called "groups" in the default Google contacts app, but I think that labels are basically the same thing as "groups".

Comment: Similar approach to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160906/131553) //In the trigger, use *groups*. I am not aware of any way to do it within Android

Comment: I haven't tried using groups but it should work as Labels are groups; contacts app help says *You can group contacts together using labels*

Answer (score -1):

Google should be ashamed for this stepback.
Up to android 10 contacts were organized in "groups" (not "labels") and you could
set ringtone per group. Not only in Samsung mobiles (who still have this feature)
but other vendors as well (eg I have it in Huawei P30 Pro).
In Android 11 and 12 they moved to "labels" and "labels" can't have rigntone per
"label".

I repeat, this is a shame. Setting different per group of contacts is essential.
It's a feature it was available in legacy phones (I recall using it in Nokia 6210,
Nokia 6310i and even older), in Nokia/Symbian touch phone C3-100 and all previous android phone up to 10, inclusive.

For example my usage scenario is that I use Bluetooth headset and phone is in my
pocket. I don't take phone out of the pocket to answer the call, I answer it from headset. Setting different ringtone per group I can't tell who calls me but I get an idea, it's someone from work, from family, a friend etc.
Alternative to set rigntone contact by contact is stupid, you can't do it when you have hundreds of contacts!

Hey Google, do you hear us? So many people ask you to bring this feature back.
Are you serious? Prove it! Don't become Microsoft!!!

Costas

Comment: I'm afraid you're barking up the wrong tree. This site is not affiliated with Google, and Google doesn't seem to read feedbacks/critiques from here. Also, this doesn't have anything to do with the Android version, but specifically about the Google Contacts app because "labels" are also shown on Android 7 (independent of the Android version). Samsung and Huawei may have their own Contacts app and may behave differently from Google Contacts though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/248872)