# Silence notifications from specific contact at certain times

Tags: notifications, google-pixel, android-13

(Pixel 7, Android 13) I currently use bedtime mode to put my phone into DND at night before I go to bed to silence all notifications and all that jazz. I know you can set specific contacts to be able to get through DND for important calls/etc.

I actually want to do the *opposite*. I want to be able to enable a DND mode for specific contacts at night so I don't receive messages/calls from them after a certain time.

Ex: I don't want to receive texts or calls from Billy after 9pm because he's a party animal and drunk texts me all night. Everyone else is fine and lets me sleep.

Is there anything in Android built in to do this? I'm open to using other apps too.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160816/how-to-set-one-ringtone-for-contacts-and-another-for-non-contacts/160906#160906) led me to what I was looking for.
MacroDroid seems to be what I need for this, and it has a lot of ways to go about it (monitoring SMS received, clearing notifications, or clearing notifications with specific text, etc.). I've already started looking into using it for things other than what I originally got it for too!

As suggested, the macro that worked for me in MacDroid was very simple:

- Triggers

  - Notifications Received

    - Contains: [contact name] (Messages)
- Actions

  - Clear Notifications

    - Any Content (Messages)
- Constraints

  - Time of Day: [start time] - [end time]

[Screenshot of the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N83hb.png) where the crossed-out pieces are the contact name(s).

It effectively silences notifications from those specific contacts during the provided window, I'll only see their messages if I go to the main messages inbox, even if it's in group chats!

Comment: Indeed, MacroDroid can be used for [a lot of things](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=MacroDroid) // Best part is it's easy to learn. +1// See *templates* section of the app for more